# Use Mongo aggregate to count number of docs in a collection (specific value)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My schema for a collection is thus:

```
var RecommendationSchema = new Schema({
    tagId: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'Tag'
    },
    recommenderID: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    recommendedID: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
});
```

So each time someone is "recommended", I populate a new document in this collection. What I'm trying to do, is see who has the most "recommendations" (documents) for a given `tagId`. So far I have:

```
recommendationModel.aggregate({
            $group: {
                _id: '$tagId',
                total_recommendations: {
                    $sum: 1
                }
            }
        },
        function(err, results) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }
            return res.send(results);
        }
    );
```

but this yields:

```
     [ { _id: 539587cdd43cfb1f31c3b7a0, total_recommendations: 1 },
09:10:19 web.1  |   { _id: 539587ead43cfb1f31c3b7a5, total_recommendations: 1 },
09:10:19 web.1  |   { _id: 539587dbd43cfb1f31c3b7a2, total_recommendations: 2 },
09:10:19 web.1  |   { _id: 539587c9d43cfb1f31c3b79f, total_recommendations: 2 },
09:10:19 web.1  |   { _id: 539587c3d43cfb1f31c3b79e, total_recommendations: 2 } ]
```

So it's just telling me how many documents for each `tagId`. How can I get a dataset of, for example:

(pseudo)

```
tagId: 123456789
recommendedId: xyz
total_recommendations: 10

tagId: 123456789
recommendedId: abc
total_recommendations: 4

tagId: 123456789
recommendedId: mno
total_recommendations: 7
```

Is this possible (using Mongoose with Node.js for Mongo access)?

Comment: You cannot do that. The detail you are looking for is all in different collections. If you want to see the detail and use aggregate functions then you need to embed. Mongoose populate is not magic, it's just shorthand for querying other collections that you do not see.

Comment: @NeilLunn Probably my misunderstanding here, but what other information would mongo need to fulfil this query? Surely the information is all in this collection?

Comment: Your schema uses referencing, as shown by the `Ref` properties on the definitions. This refers to the name of an external model, so another collection, that actually has the associated field data that you are looking for in your sample output. All that is in the collection defined by the schema for this model is just the `_id` values of those items in other collections. You most likely really want embedding, and this is a typical schema resulting from traditional relational model thinking. But it does not apply well to MongoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To split the `tagId` counts by `recommendedId` put both fields into the `_id` of your `$group`:

```js
recommendationModel.aggregate({
        $group: {
            _id: {
                tagId: '$tagId',
                recommendedId: '$recommendedId'
            },
            total_recommendations: {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
    },
    function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        return res.send(results);
    }
);
```